# Is it posible to use only one call to database when pagination in Java?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, pagination, criteriaquery

If the pagesize is 10 and `pageNumber` is 0, for the given condition, if I I get 50 documents from mongodb, then `total_documents` should be 50 and `msList` should have the details of 1st 10 documents(DTO's)(since the `pageNumber` is 0 i.e. pagination).

```java
Query query = new Query();
List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
criteria.add(Criteria.where("di.ai").in(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("123"))));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[criteria.size()])));
Long total_documents = this.mongoTemplate.count(query, NSDTO.class, MONGODB_MESSAGE_COLLECTION);
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of((pageNumber - 1), pageSize);
query.with(pageable);    
List<NSDTO> nsList= this.mongoTemplate.find(query, NSDTO.class, MONGODB_MESSAGE_COLLECTION);"
```

I am able to achieve this functionality using the above code, but the problem here is we are making mongodb calls 2 times.

Would it be possible to achieve the same functionality using only one mongodb call?

Could someone please help on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

When pagination is performed, usually, use two queries: first query will count a total size, second query returns actual records using two parameters: `pageNumber` and `pageSize`.

These two queries are independent of each other and cannot be joined. So, it's impossible using CreteriaQuery API and in pagination themselves.

Comment: But since we are making 2 calls to mongo db its costing us more with respect to performance. What else can we do to improve performance if 2 calls to mongodb can't be avoided

Comment: I don't understand what's performance  you talking. Do you mean a query performance or database performance? For database 1 or 2 queries makes no difference, the database performance admit it. If you want optimize performance of query then look at your `explain()` and use indexes for fields in the where condition. You can read further [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) is your guide.

Comment: performance issue is code going to mongodb twice will increase the response time right, My only question is can we achieve paginantion as well as total result set count from a single mongodb call from code

Comment: It isn't an issue, and as I said in the answer you can't.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the pagination in one call with `$facet`. Just be reminded not to have too large page size since it would fail due to [16MB MongoDB document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "paginationMeta": [
        {
          "$match": {
            //your match criteria here
            
          }
        },
        {
          "$count": "total_documents"
        }
      ],
      page: [
        {
          "$match": {
            //your match criteria here
            
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            key: 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$skip": 20
        },
        {
          "$limit": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cqx9Y2wjsjP)

Comment: Hi by any chance can you give me a java spring code please if possible

Comment: @Swetha it is not possible.